# getx value not listen on button click

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I want to listen to value from the button press with getx, but the getx value won't change except hot reload is pressed manually.

```
RxBool visible = false.obs;


Visibility(
visible: statusRequest!
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .contains("canceled") ||
                                        statusRequest!
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .contains("rejected")
                                    ? true
                                    : false,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: size.width * 0.9,
                                  height: size.height * 0.06,
                                  child: Obx(
                                    () => ElevatedButton(
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                            backgroundColor: kButtonColor),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          print("Request button tapped");
                                          final form = formKey.currentState!;
                                          setState(() {
                                            visible.value = !visible.value;
                                            print('visibel ' +
                                                visible.toString());
                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: RichText(
                                          text: TextSpan(children: [
                                            TextSpan(
                                              text: !visible.value
                                                  ? 'Edit Settlement'
                                                  : 'Cancel Edit',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                          ]),
                                        )),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                
),
```

and in this the function I call from `initState`

```
addPerDateDraft(int i) async {
    dynamicPerDate.add(DynamicSettlementPerDate(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        isEdit: visible,
        Date: dataListTravelAdvance[0].settlementDetail![i].claimDate,
        listDetail: dataListTravelAdvance[0].settlementDetail![i].detail!.obs));
    print('date draft added $i');
    setState(() {});
  }
```

inside class `DynamicSettlementPerDate` there a func to create a category object from `CategorySettlement`.

```
addCategoryPerDateFromDraft() {
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; widget.listDetail!.length > i; i++) {
        var typeClaim = widget.listDetail![i].typeClaim;
        var totalClaim = widget.listDetail![i].totalClaim!.obs;

        widget.listCategorySettlement!.add(CategorySettlement(
          isEdit: widget.isEdit,
          selectedCategory: typeClaim,
          amountCategory: totalClaim,
        ));
      }
    });
    print('new CategorySettlement from draft added');
    print('${widget.listCategorySettlement}');
  }
```

inside `CategorySettlement` is a text field and dropdown that I want to disable/enable from the main class with `isEdit`.

```
lass CategorySettlement extends StatefulWidget {
  String? selectedCategory;
  RxInt? amountCategory;
  String? Function(String?)? validators;
  TextEditingController? amountController;
  RxBool? isEdit;
  CategorySettlement(
      {Key? key,
      this.validators,
      this.selectedCategory,
      this.amountCategory,
      this.amountController,
      this.isEdit})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CategorySettlementState createState() => _CategorySettlementState();
}
```

Comment: I clearly see that you're not wrapping the whole visibility widget with an Obx and it's visible property do not rely actually on your RxBool visible, so it will not update

Comment: any state update you will manage, will be exclusive to the Obx, so the visibility widget do not rely on any state management widget, so it will not get updated automatically until you do a manually hot reload

Comment: I have try to wrap the `Visibilty` widget with Obx but the value doesn't change.

Comment: the visible property do not rely really on your RxBool visible variable, so it will not update, wrapping visibility widgetswith obx, and set the visible property like this: visible: visible.value, now every time you do visible.value = true or visible.value = false, your widget should show/hide

Comment: now you should implement your logic which gives the visible a new value each time in some separate place so your visibility widget will show/hide based on, Obx doesn't know anything else than Rx variables, so you should not expect that it will update because of your data is changed